# Ruby on rails, paste a function into textarea and execute it

Tags: ruby-on-rails

In my application I have a text area, where a user can paste a function that operates on a specific hash holding different data about the client.

```
<label >Function</label><textarea class="text" rows ="20" cols ="100" id="cell_option"><%=frst%></textarea>
```

A user would like to to count how many items of a specific category were bought by a client.
lets say a hash is of a form `data = [date][category][item][price]`.
So, the user would like to a post a function like

```
res = 0
data.each do |date,val|
     val.each do |cat, val_cat|
          if cat == "Cosmetics"
            res = res +1
          end
    end
end
return res
```

The idea is to give a user as much possibility to operate and analyze the data as possible.
The only my problem is that in text area the function will be saved as a string and I did not find how I can execute a string so that ruby recognizes it as a function, operating on data.
Data is given explicitly:

```
def execute_user_function(data)

**body from text area**

end
```

**edit: I am sure I want to do this. I need it, I am aware of the consequences.**

Comment: It's quite a bad idea to execute user-provided code.

Comment: I know but I need it.

Comment: Are you sure you want to do this?

Comment: I am sure I want to do this.

Comment: try using eval method

Comment: @advishnuprasad I tried it. That is what is saved in the database: res = 0\ndata = dat['22.12.2012']\ndata.each do |pk2, v_pk2|\nv_pk2.each do |lfn,pk3s|\n\n\npk3s.each do |pk3,v_pk3|\nif pk3 == 'Cosmetics' or pk3 == 'Car items'\n\nv_pk3['value_number']\nend\n\nend\nend\nend\nback = {}\nback['value_number'] = res\nback['value_string'] = nil\nreturn back"

and eval tells me that it has problems with return and == sign